# No line matching interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian is supported

Tags: java, javafx, audio

Cant seem to get it to work , even compressed the wav file in the format
Its on the webserver and its not fetching the music , it worked fine for me a couple of months ago and now it doesnt, can anyone help?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
    AppFrame frame = new AppFrame();
    frame.build();
    new Thread(new StatusChecker(Constants.SERVER_IP, Constants.SERVER_PORT)).start();
    popup = new PopupFrame();

       URL url = new URL(
               "http://test.com/test/13.wav");
           Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
           AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
               getAudioInputStream( url );
           clip.open(ais);
           clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {


               }
           });
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: At what point is the code failing?

Comment: worked it out thanks . whas a cache problem